# How to import SQLite data into DuckDB?

Tags: sqlite, duckdb

How to import SQLite data into DuckDB? Or is it possible to query the SQLite data files directly from DuckDB? A presentation from author of DuckDB mentioned such a feature.

Answer (score 3):

yes it is possible to scan SQLite db files directly by using the [sqlite extension](https://github.com/duckdblabs/sqlite_scanner)

You first will need to install and load it

```sql
INSTALL sqlite_scanner
LOAD sqlite_scanner
CALL sqlite_attach('your_sqlite_db.db');
```

Then you should be able to query the sqlite tables.

Answer (score 0):

While the sqlite scanner is a very handy tool, if you would need to do an ETL style data migration with table/column filtering/mapping, value mappings etc., check out the SyncLite DB Replication tool at

https://www.synclite.io/

Additionally, SyncLite provides SQLite connector for numerous instances of applications each creating several SQLite databases, to perform a real-time database replication/consolidation into one or more databases/data warehouses/data lakes of your choice.

This gives rise to many interesting architectural possibilities for building all kinds of data intensive applications around SQLite and DuckDB to harness the best out of both.

Answer (score 0):

```
I couldn't connect sqlite3 to duckdb directly in python,
attach, sqlite_scanner, etc.
Then, I try.
polars can read sqlite3 by pl.read_database().
duckdb can directly handle polars.DataFrame as a table.

Using this, I could use sqlite3 by polars and duckdb.
I found that Polars sql can do nearly duckdb.
```